# Swift understand generics with enums

Tags: ios, swift

I have following code written by other person:

```
public enum MSEntity<T : Metable> {
    case meta(MSMeta)
    case entity(T)

    public func value() -> T? {
        guard case let MSEntity.entity(value) = self else {
            return nil
        }
        return value
    }

    public func objectMeta() -> MSMeta {
        switch self {
        case .entity(let entity): return entity.meta
        case .meta(let meta): return meta
        }
    }
}
```

I have following questions:

1) what is the point of doing case entity(T)? What is "value" of that enum case and for what it may be used for?

2) I can't understand `public func value()` func.
What is that guard checking? What is value? Can someone provide an example where similar code may be useful?

Comment: First of all you should learn all these concepts clearly, otherwise there's no meaning how many examples you see. You won't understand generic types or guard conditions etc...

Comment: @DipakKacha thanks, i'm in processing doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The enum seems to represent an object that can either only contain metadata or a entity with metadata.

It has 2 cases: `meta` represents an object with only metadata and that metadata is this case's associated value, `entity` represents an object that has a entity and metadata. This case's associated value is the object's entity, which contains metadata (so the constraint on `T` is `Metable`)

> what is the point of doing case entity(T)? What is "value" of that enum case and for what it may be used for?

Well, for this you have to look at the docs or ask the person who wrote the code. As far as I'm concerned, `MSEntity` is an object that has 2 states:

- only metadata (`meta` case)
- entity and metadata (`entity` case)

So the `entity` case is there to represent that.

> I can't understand public func value() func. What is that guard checking? What is value?

The `value` function seems to return the object's entity, but what if this object has no entity (i.e. `self` is actually in the `meta` case)? The author of this code decided to return `nil`. That is why there is a check: if `self` is in the `meta` case. The word `value` is part of the pattern matching. It might be clearer if I wrote it like this:

```
guard case let MSEntity.entity(let value) = self else {
```

Whatever is in the associated value of `entity` case is put into a variable called `value`, so that you can return it later.

Comment: thank you for detailed comment, i also have a question, please have a look at :         case .entity(let entity): return entity.meta
What is a point to provide let entity in round brackets? What is meaning of this?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban That denotes a pattern that matches the associated value of that enum case. In plain words, it means "match a case of `entity` and match its associated value and put the associated value into a variable called `entity`"

Answer (score 1):

The `(MSMeta)` and `(T)` [*associated values*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID148) of the `meta` and `entity` cases, respectively.

The `value()` method (which IMO should be a computed property of type `T?`, rather than a function of type `() -> T?`) returns the associated value of the `entity` case, if `self` is `entity`, otherwise it returns `nil` (when the `self` is `meta`).

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban http://alisoftware.github.io/swift/pattern-matching/2016/05/16/pattern-matching-4/

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban `What is that guard checking?` It's a pattern matching expression, similar to those in a switch statement. `guard case let  MSEntity.entity(value) = self else { return nil }` works just like `switch self { case let MSEntity.entity(value): /* do something with value */; default: return nil }`